# Using jQuery to populate a DropDownListFor

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I would like to know if it is even possible to combine jQuery with a @Html.DropDownListFor in a strongly typed view, as I am beginning to suspect that either it isn't, or my approach to this problem is flawed.

Model:

```
public class NewUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string ConfirmEmail { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    public SelectListItem DOBDay { get; set; }
    public SelectListItem DOBMonth { get; set; }
    public SelectListItem DOBYear { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model test.Models.NewUser

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("RegisterUser", "Register", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "" }))
{
    <div>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.FirstName, new { @class = "big_i", @watermark = "First name" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.LastName, new { @class = "big_i", @watermark = "Last name" })
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.EmailAddress, new { @class = "big_i long_i", @watermark = "E-mail address" })
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.ConfirmEmail, new { @class = "big_i long_i", @watermark = "Confirm e-mail address" })
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => Model.Password, new { @class = "big_i long_i", @watermark = "Password" })
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => Model.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "big_i long_i", @watermark = "Confirm password" })
    </div>
    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <h2>
                Date of birth</h2>
            <div id="reg_date_control" class="date_control">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.DOBDay, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "Day: ", new { @class = "dc-days big_i" })
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.DOBMonth, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "Month: ", new { @class = "dc-months big_i" })
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.DOBYear, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "Year: ", new { @class = "dc-years big_i" })
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
}
```

Controller action for form submit:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RegisterUser(Models.NewUser model)
{
    string firstName = model.FirstName;
    string lastName = model.LastName;
    string email = model.EmailAddress;
    string confirm_email = model.ConfirmEmail;
    string password = model.Password;
    string confirm_password = model.ConfirmPassword;
    string dob_month = model.DOBMonth.Value; // an error is raised here
    return View();
}
```

I am trying to initially bind the @Html.DropDownListFor with an empty list, which the jQuery will then populate.  I won't paste the jQuery code here, it is basically populating each DOB drop down with the valid number of days in a selected month.

The lists populate fine.  However, DOBDay, DOBMonth, and DOBYear are always null.  I expect that using Enumerable.Empty() is my problem, but having said that, I have tried populating the dropdowns like so:

```
@model gs_mvc.Models.NewUser

@{
    string[] months = new[]{"January", "February", "March", "April", "etc"};
    var items = new List<SelectListItem>();
    for (int i = 0; i < months.Length; i++) {
        items.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = i.ToString(), Text = months[i] });
    }
}

...

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.DOBMonth, items, "Month: ", new { @class = "big_i" })
```

which also gives a null value.

At this point, I believe that my best bet would be to move the functionality of my jQuery script to C#, and do an AJAX call each time the dropdowns are changed.  However, I wanted to check here first that I'm not missing something blindingly obvious that would allow me to do what I'm trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that the values on the model for month, day, and year should probably be `int` not `SelectListItem`.  `SelectListItem` is used to build the options, since it has both the Text and Value properties, but what you want to and will receive back are just the values - not Text/Value pairs.  Of course, you probably want to make them nullable so that you're sure that you're receiving values from the POST rather than just having them default to zero.

```
public class NewUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string ConfirmEmail { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    public int? DOBDay { get; set; }
    public int? DOBMonth { get; set; }
    public int? DOBYear { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this was the problem.  I knew it would be something simple.  Thank you very much.